# how to call plugin for each select with certain class

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, javascript

I want to call jquery plugin function for every select element which has class name `myclas`.

How to achieve that?

This is how I call my function:

```
$('.myclass').myplugin({
     name:$('select').attr('name'),
     hidden_value:$('input[type=hidden]').attr('name')
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By iterating

```
$('.myclass').each(function(i,ele) {
     $(ele).myplugin({
         name: ele.name,
         hidden_value: $('input[type=hidden]', ele).prop('name')
    });
});
```

Comment: can you explain me this `i` and `ele`? what are they representing

Comment: `i` is just a counter, and `ele` is the current element being iterated. They are the built in parameters in jQuery's `.each()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.myclass').each(function(){
 $(this).myplugin({
     name:$('select').attr('name'),
     hidden_value:$('input[type=hidden]').attr('name')
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('select.myclass').each(function(){
   $(this).myplugin({
       name:$(this).attr('name'), // current select.myclass object attr
       hidden_value:$('input[type=hidden]').attr('name')
   });
});
```

If you give your plugin code then it is more easy to understand your problem.